# Qt Quick Static Images

Tags: image, qt, static, qt-creator, qml

I have compiled Qt Statically and I have used it to compile my application. My exe runs anywhere but it only shows something if there is a qml/Raker/images folder in the same directory as my exe but I want the image to be included in my exe. In qml I access the image through "images/layer_0.png"(This is only one out of 20). I have read something about a resource file but I can't completely understand it. I'm sure how to do this If any of you could just help. I also want to know if Qt Creator has some built in way of doing this.

Comment: Not sure if this applies, but do you use a `resources.qrc` file? It allows you to embed images without dealing with paths.

Comment: No I'm not sure how to use it and I want want to know if Qt Creator can create one automaticcly

Comment: Yes, it can: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-using-qt-designer.html#managing-image-resources

Comment: Do I need to also include my qml file for it to run?

Comment: No, it should compile with your `.ui` files.

Comment: I don't have a .ui because it's a Qt Quick app

Comment: Can't help you with then, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done and it is built into Qt. The steps are as follows:

1. In Qt Creator, right click on your project, choose "add new", select Qt Resource File chose a name and location
2. Double click on file to open it in the resource editor
3. Click on Add->Add Prefix to add the prefix to the file
4. Click on Add->Add File to add each of your image files
5. To access files using the QResources Scheme, prefix them with ":/" as in ":/images/icon.png"

Alternatively to quickly "convert" all relative image paths to be accessed as resources, use the QResources scheme to set your view source in qml:
`view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));`

For more information have a look at:

- [How to use Resource Editor with Qt Creator](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Resource_Editor_with_Qt_Creator)
- [managing resource files with the qt resource system](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html#managing-resource-files-with-the-qt-resource-system)

Comment: Not sure if that edit was really worth it, considering that both links are broken.